# How to create a save button with popup error message in Apex Oracle

Tags: oracle, button, popup, save, oracle-apex

I would like to create a save button in a page in my apex application. If the user clicks the button and if the column value is not unique then the user should get a pop up message saying "Data already exists" else it should be "Data successfully added".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With built-in Apex capabilities:

- button submits page
- create **validation** (function that returns error text) which checks whether value already exists in a table; if so, return appropriate message:

  ```
  declare
    l_cnt number;
  begin
    select count(*) 
      into l_cnt
      from your_table
      where some_value = :P1_SOME_ITEM;

    if l_cnt > 0 then
       return 'Data already exists';
    end if;
  end;
  ```
- create **process** that executes PL/SQL code which actually does *nothing*:

  ```
  null;
  ```

  but its "Success message" says "Data successfully added'